# Reversed group by with multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle12c

Hi i'm not sure if this possible in oracle database or any one but is possible to make this:

What i have:

```
Document   | Volume    | BAC     | CO
-----------|-----------|---------|---------
TA1        | 4         | 2       | 0
```

What i want:

```
Document   | Volume    | BAC     | CO      | ID
-----------|-----------|---------|---------|---------
TA1        | 1         | 0       | 0       | 1
TA1        | 1         | 0       | 0       | 2
TA1        | 1         | 0       | 0       | 3
TA1        | 1         | 0       | 0       | 4
TA1        | 0         | 1       | 0       | 5
TA1        | 0         | 1       | 0       | 6
```

I tried using `WITH` but it's just mess in my `Sqldevelopper` now couldn't even come close to it knowing that `WITH` can't be used twice or been in `UNION`.

PS: Number of rows need to be equal to (Volume + Bac + CO).

Is this operation possible in ORACLE 12?

Comment: How are you getting six rows rather than four rows?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff yes the point is that number of rows equal volume + bac + CO

Comment: Maybe `Volume + BAC` ? Though then I would expect `1` on `BAC` with `ID(5,6)`

Comment: I made an important change in my second table. sorry @sagi

Comment: How big can the number be? Infinity or say up to 10 or something?

Comment: it can't be over than 30 but is this important?

Comment: Whether that is important depends on the solution. Preferably a solution should NOT depend on such "magic numbers", unless doing so results in a much simpler or more efficient approach. Not likely with this problem.

Comment: Also, a good solution should allow the possibility that the input table has more than one row, and produce the correct result in that case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and it only goes over the data once. It's a simple application of hierarchical query.

I added more test data; note that in the case of TA3, there should be no rows in the output (because all three values in the row are 0).

```
with
     test_data ( document, volume, bac, co ) as (
       select 'TA1', 4, 2, 0 from dual union all
       select 'TA2', 0, 0, 1 from dual union all
       select 'TA5', 0, 0, 0 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; actual solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select document,
       case when level <= volume                           then 1 else 0 end as volume,
       case when level >  volume and level <= volume + bac then 1 else 0 end as bac,
       case when level >  volume + bac                     then 1 else 0 end as co,
       level as id
from   test_data
where  volume + bac + co > 0
connect by level <= volume + bac + co
    and prior document = document
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by document, id    --  ORDER BY is optional
;

DOC     VOLUME        BAC         CO         ID
--- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
TA1          1          0          0          1
TA1          1          0          0          2
TA1          1          0          0          3
TA1          1          0          0          4
TA1          0          1          0          5
TA1          0          1          0          6
TA2          0          0          1          1

 7 rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -> First, create a temporary derived table containing the amount of rows equal to the maximum number allowed :

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE AS
SELECT s.num_col,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) as rnk 
 FROM (
     SELECT 1 as num_col FROM dual
     UNION ALL SELECT 1 as num_col FROM dual
     UNION ALL SELECT 1 as num_col FROM dual 
     UNION ALL SELECT 1 as num_col FROM dual
     ...... As many necessary) s
```

Then, use this:

```
SELECT p.num_col as volume,0 as BAC,0 as CO
FROM TMP_TABLE p
JOIN YourTable t
 ON(t.Volume >= p.rnk)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0 as volume,p.num_col as BAC,0 as CO
FROM TMP_TABLE p
JOIN YourTable t
 ON(t.BAC >= p.rnk)
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 as volume,0 as BAC,p.num_col as CO
FROM TMP_TABLE p
JOIN YourTable t
 ON(t.CO >= p.rnk)
```

Comment: I tried the first SELECT and it give't me 6 rows wich wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select      t.document
           ,decode(t.col,'V',1,0)       as volume
           ,decode(t.col,'B',1,0)       as bac
           ,decode(t.col,'C',1,0)       as co
           ,row_number () over 
           (
               partition by t.document order by decode(t.col,'V',1,'B',2,'C',3)
           ) as id

from              t unpivot (n for col in (volume as 'V',bac as 'B',co as 'C')) t                       
            join  (select level as n from dual connect by level <= (select max(greatest(volume,bac,co)) from t)) c
            on    c.n <= t.n
 ;
```

or

```
select      t.document
           ,decode(t.col,'V',1,0)       as volume
           ,decode(t.col,'B',1,0)       as bac
           ,decode(t.col,'C',1,0)       as co
           ,t.pre + c.n                 as id

from              (select t.*,0 as pre_v,volume as pre_b,volume+bac as pre_c from t) t 
                          unpivot ((n,pre) for col in ((volume,pre_v) as 'V',(bac,pre_b) as 'B',(co,pre_c) as 'C')) t

            join  (select level as n from dual connect by level <= (select max(greatest(volume,bac,co)) from t)) c
            on    c.n <= t.n

 order by   1,id
 ;
```

or

```
with    r (col,Document,col_val,n,id) as
        (
            select  c.col,t.Document,decode (c.col,1,t.Volume,2,t.BAC,3,t.CO),1,decode (c.col,1,1,2,t.Volume+1,3,t.Volume+t.BAC+1)
            from    t cross join (select level as col from dual connect by level <= 3) c
            where   decode (c.col,1,t.Volume,2,t.BAC,3,t.CO) > 0

            union all  

            select  r.col,r.Document,r.col_val,r.n+1,r.id+1
            from    r join (select level as col from dual connect by level <= 3) c
                    on c.col = r.col and r.n < r.col_val 
        )

select  Document
       ,decode (col,1,1,0)      as Volume
       ,decode (col,2,1,0)      as BAC
       ,decode (col,3,1,0)      as CO
       ,id

from    r

order by 1,5
;
```

or

```
with    r_Volume (Document,col_val,Volume,Bac,Co,n) as (select Document,Volume,1,0,0,1 from t where Volume > 0 union all select Document,col_val,Volume,Bac,Co,n+1 from r_Volume where n < col_val)
       ,r_Bac    (Document,col_val,Volume,Bac,Co,n) as (select Document,Bac   ,0,1,0,1 from t where Bac    > 0 union all select Document,col_val,Volume,Bac,Co,n+1 from r_Bac    where n < col_val)
       ,r_Co     (Document,col_val,Volume,Bac,Co,n) as (select Document,Co    ,0,0,1,1 from t where Co     > 0 union all select Document,col_val,Volume,Bac,Co,n+1 from r_Co     where n < col_val)

select  Document,Volume,Bac,Co,row_number () over (partition by Document order by Volume desc,Bac desc,Co desc) as id

from    (             select Document,Volume,Bac,Co from r_Volume
         union all    select Document,Volume,Bac,Co from r_Bac
         union all    select Document,Volume,Bac,Co from r_Co
        ) r
;
```

Comment: @sagi, what am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't know why it occurred to you, just fixed it for you:)

Comment: Your two newest solutions (added at the top) will fail if any of the counts (volume, bac, or co) is greater than 30.  For that reason your recursive solution is better.

Comment: @Sentinel, The PO was asked about that and answered - "it can't be over than 30", but you know what? give me 1 minute

Comment: That comment must have come up after I started looking at the Q and concocting my response ;) I've voted up those comments now so they don't get hidden.

Comment: @Sentinel, you can recheck the top 2 answers

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve this problem:

```
WITH sample_data( document, volume, bac, co ) AS (
  SELECT 'TA1', 4, 2, 0
    FROM dual
)
, recursive( document, col_id, col_cnt, id ) AS (
  SELECT document -- First unpivot the data for each document
       , col_id
       , col_cnt
       , SUM( col_cnt ) over( partition BY document order by col_id ) - col_cnt + 1
    FROM sample_data UNPIVOT( col_cnt FOR col_id IN( volume AS 1,
                                                     bac    AS 2,
                                                     co     AS 3 ) )
   WHERE col_cnt > 0 -- But throw away rows with zero col_cnts.

  UNION ALL

  SELECT document
       , col_id
       , col_cnt - 1 -- Recursively decrement the col_cnt
       , id      + 1 -- and increment id
    FROM recursive
   WHERE col_cnt > 1 -- until col_cnt is no longer > 1
)
SELECT document -- Finally pivot the recursive data
     , volume   -- back to its original columns
     , bac
     , co
     , id
  FROM recursive PIVOT( COUNT( * ) FOR col_id IN( 1 AS volume, 2 AS bac, 3 AS co ) )
 ORDER BY document
     , id;
```